# How to extract the bundle.js file in Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have this problem of not remembering the things I did the first time.

Before I was able to extract the bundle.js file and upload through a ftp server without going through the hassle of deploying through heroku.

Comment: Please, do some google.

Comment: i have tried that, then i assume you must know

Comment: Share the process you have tried.

Comment: i looked through my search history, but i couldnt find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack generates static files and puts them to a directory defined in your webpack config file. So, you can just run `webpack` in Terminal and this will generate files. After that, you can upload them using FTP.