# unpack webpack javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack is using [terser](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) to minify js files

1. Does webpack always minifies the libraries using their sources ? (even if a minified version exists in the library )
2. Is there a way to unpack & extract the minified libraries ? this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47765850/2655092) is outdates
3. does webpack has a flag to save minified versions aside ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Webpack first performs tree shaking and combines the libraries into a bundle before minifying this bundle
2. Minification (just like compilation from high-level language into machine code) is irreversible transformation
3. If you want to have both minified (for production) and unminified (for debugging) verions of the bundle - you will have to run Webpack twice, with 2 different config files